# Evento para calcular itens pesquisados na tabela

Tags: javascript, jquery, funções

Preciso calcular os itens da tabela e mostrar em determinado campo da minha pagina.

Existe um campo de busca com alguns filtros, conforme é pesquisado aparecem os pacientes na tabela, com o evento eu queria ouvir os pacientes conforme são pesquisados e mostrar o resultado (quantidade de pacientes que foram encontrados) em outro campo.

O **id="countPacientes"** é um **< span >** onde deve aparecer o número de pacientes pesquisados.

**.pacientes-table-plugin** é a minha tabela

O meu evento no .js está assim:

```
Pacientes.prototype = {
     $('.pacientes-table-plugin').on('change', function(){
          self.count_pac();
     });
}
```

**E minha função assim:**

```
count_pac : function(){
     const t = $('.pacientes-table-plugin tr').length;
     $('#countPacientes').text(t);
}
```

Porém meu evento não está funcionando

Comment: Você quer contar a quantidade de linhas, de colunas ou de células?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Calcular itens de uma tabela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/326347/calcular-itens-de-uma-tabela)

Comment: Melhor continuar editando sua pergunta original, ao invés de abrir duas novas perguntas com o mesmo conteúdo.

Comment: A quantidade de linhas